# How to set an attribute of a DOM element in Clojurescript?

Tags: clojurescript

I wish to set the "value" property of an "input" element using Clojurescript, but I am having trouble with the syntax of setProperties in goog.com. Has anyone got a working example?

**Update
------**

This seems to work:

```
(goog.dom.setProperties 
 (goog.dom/getElement "element-name")
 (clj->js {:value "text"}))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you need to create throwaway JS objects for use with JS APIs, you can do so directly using  `js-obj`:

```
(js-obj "value" "text")
;; produces {"value": "text"} in the compiled output
```

Of course if you already have a ClojureScript map with the appropriate entries, `clj->js` will be more convenient.

More importantly, you might want to consider switching to a ClojureScript library for DOM manipulation. Several are available:

- Luke VanderHart's [Domina](https://github.com/levand/domina), which might have been the first one, is used by Enfocus (listed below) and [Pedestal](http://pedestal.io/);
- Prismatic's [dommy](https://github.com/Prismatic/dommy), notable due to its own merits as well as the very entertaining blog posts about it on [Prismatic's blog](http://blog.getprismatic.com/) (which can serve as a great introduction to the benefits of macros: [first one](http://blog.getprismatic.com/blog/2013/1/14/bringing-functional-to-the-frontend-clojure-clojurescript-for-the-web), [second one](http://blog.getprismatic.com/blog/2013/1/22/the-magic-of-macros-lighting-fast-templating-in-clojurescript), [third one](http://blog.getprismatic.com/blog/2013/4/29/faster-better-dom-manipulation-with-dommy-and-clojurescript));
- Creighton Kirkendall's [Enfocus](https://github.com/ckirkendall/enfocus), which is in a nutshell an [Enlive](https://github.com/cgrand/enlive)-like library for ClojureScript, which is awesome;
- Kevin Lynagh's [Singult](https://github.com/lynaghk/singult), which is a Hiccup-style library for ClojureScript with cool functionality for merging in changes to the DOM, rather than rerendering from scratch.