# In ClojureScript, Set multiple properties of a javascript object at once

Tags: interop, clojurescript

I am using doto to assign properties of a Dom element in ClojureScript, as below:

```clj
(let [img
          (doto (.createElement js/document "img")
            (set! -src "bunny-512.png")
            (set! -height 64)
            (set! -width 64))]
;...
)
```

Is there a way to do set all the properties at once via a map of properties+values instead?

Was thinking something like:

```clj
(let [img (.createElement js/document "img")]
  (set! img {:src "bunny-512.png" :height 64 :width 64})
```

But that does not work ...

Comment: This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545607/how-to-set-an-attribute-of-a-dom-element-in-clojurescript contains an example, that supposedly works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
(defn set-props [o property-map] 
  (doseq [[k v] property-map] 
    (.setAttribute o (name k) v)))
```

Test:

```
(def mg (.createElement js/document "img"))

cljs.user=> (set-props mg {:src "foo.png" :height 128 :width 128})
nil

cljs.user=> (.-src mg)
".../foo.png"

cljs.user=> (.-width mg)
128

cljs.user=> (.-height mg)
128
```

Comment: I am guessing no function nor macro to do this from core ?